# AMI操作をトリガーする方法

Tags: aws, aws-cloudwatch

[AMI削除時にスナップショットも自動で削除するCloudWatch Events](https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/aws/ami-and-snapshot-delete/)
と同じことをしたいのですが
AWS Console の Cloud Watch ルール画面で
DeregisterImage というイベントが選択できません

image ではなく snapshot に関わるイベントしか選べないのですが
どうすればイメージの作成や削除をトリガーにできるのでしょうか

直接 JSON で指定しようにもイベントの detail や type がわかりません

画像のUIは英語表記でこちらは日本語表記で使っているのですが
言語によってコンソールの選択肢に違いがあるのでしょうか
それとも選択できるイベントがリージョンによって限られてるということなんでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

[CloudWatch Events Event Examples From Supported Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html)
の中に AMI 作成/削除のイベントが見当たりません。
仕様が変わったのでしょうか？

CloudTrail のログから `RegisterImage`, `DeregisterImage` を拾う方法が考えられますが、API 実行→ログのところで遅延があると思います。

[CloudWatch Events Event Examples From Supported Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html)
[Tutorial: Log AWS API Calls Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/LogAPICall.html)

Answer (score 1):

参考にしているURLの内容は古いのです。
事前にCloudTrailのログ記録を有効にして次のように設定してください。

サービス名: EC2
イベントタイプ: AWS API Call via CloudTrail
特定のオペレーション: DeregisterImage